# How to bind text insertion in isearch

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to have `M-u` to insert an underscore when I am in isearch (isearch-regexp and also the reverse variants).

Neither

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "M-u") 'insert-underscore)
```

nor

```
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
       (local-set-key (kbd "M-u") 'insert-underscore)
      ))
```

`insert-underscore` is my function that simply inserts "_". It works in the main frame and also in minibuffer, but I can't get it working in isearch...

Thank you!

Comment: Some errors, or? You can post more details.

Comment: No error - it just inserts the underscore directly into the buffer and not into the isearch query (which stays hanging...)

Comment: Why does simply typing an underscore into the isearch buffer not fit your needs?

Comment: By the way, there is no isearch-regexp, only isearch-forward-regexp and isearch-backward-regexp.

Comment: I'm guessing this is for ergonomic reasons?  "_" requires both pinkies.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm experimenting with this and it seems to help a lot. But I needed to get it work uniformly everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isearch doesn't use regular commands.  `(kbd "_")` along with every other
printable character is bound to a special command in `isearch-mode-map`. It's
not obvious, but a lot of things happen in "isearch-mode" when you press a
key.  Display is refreshed with new results, wrapping is a possibility, etc, etc,

You'd have to manipulate raw keyboard events to get this to work.

```
(defun underscore ()
  (interactive)
  (isearch-unread-key-sequence (list ?_)))

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "M-u") 'underscore)
```

Note that this code is not robust; for example, numeric prefix does not work.

*EDIT*: After letting percolate in my mind for a while, it occured to me that this is the exact use-case for [translation keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html)

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "M-u") (kbd "_"))
```

Ain't Emacs grand?

Comment: Thank you! Excellent answer and the code works (with the caveats you mentioned). I think for the moment this an absolutely sufficient solution. Thanks!